# i need to find out the average of the amount for consecutive way

Tags: mysql, sql

question is to return the query like below
return result like below manner!

```
101 saurav  2019-09-15  100.00     100.0000
102 mahesh  2019-09-14  200.00     150.0000
103 moja    2019-09-16  300.00     200.0000
```

for the first row same amount willbe returned as 100 as avg(Amount)
for 2nd row it should calculate sum(100+200)/2 = 150 as average
for third row is return like sum (100 +200+300)/3 = 200ā as average

Comment: 101 saurav 2019-09-15 100.00     100.0000

Comment: 102 mahesh 2019-09-14 200.00     150.0000
103 moja 2019-09-16 300.00     200.0000

Comment: What are the column names? And what is your MySQL version?

Comment: Seriously if you have a million rows you want to average over a million rows? - That's not statistically useful.

Answer (score 2):

With a self join of the table:

```
select
  t.id, t.name, t.date, t.amount,
  avg(tt.amount) averageamount
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.id <= t.id
group by t.id, t.name, t.date, t.amount
```

I used these names for your columns: `id, name, date, amount`.
This code will work in any version of MySql.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Qjq4qpgjchY6Pob8H5ywh/3).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | date                | amount | averageamount |
| --- | ------ | ------------------- | ------ | ------------- |
| 101 | saurav | 2019-09-15 00:00:00 | 100    | 100           |
| 102 | mahesh | 2019-09-14 00:00:00 | 200    | 150           |
| 103 | moja   | 2019-09-16 00:00:00 | 300    | 200           |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a window function for that purpose, like:

Assuming the following table structure and data:

```
| id  | name   | day        | value |
| --- | ------ | ---------- | ----- |
| 101 | saurav | 2019-09-15 | 100   |
| 102 | mahesh | 2019-09-14 | 200   |
| 103 | moja   | 2019-09-16 | 300   |
```

The following query:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    AVG(value) OVER(ORDER BY day) avg_value
FROM mytable t;
```

Would give you the following results:

```
| id  | name   | day        | value | avg_value |
| --- | ------ | ---------- | ----- | --------- |
| 102 | mahesh | 2019-09-14 | 200   | 200       |
| 101 | saurav | 2019-09-15 | 100   | 150       |
| 103 | moja   | 2019-09-16 | 300   | 200       |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m7si6CRMcu3qRTQ8r38Chf/1)**

Comment: Note that the default window frame is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Which can lead to [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bsccxYXv8iaSm5DNrYeHec/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using variables, but it <s>will</s> may impact performances for a large amount of data.

Assuming your 4 columns are named `id, name, date, score` you can do:

```
SET @count = 0;
SET @sum = 0;

SELECT *, (@sum:=@sum+score)/(@count:=@count+1) AS average 
FROM table1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

You can try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n8JBUhCzYh51XfhZfJ1ypc/0)

Comment: Why do you think that this will be more impactful than other methods?

Comment: By impactful you mean better than other methods? I don't, I upvoted another answer already ;)

Comment: By 'impact', I mean whatever you mean. It was your word.

Comment: Well, the variables and division will have to be computed for each returned row, which will make it slower than a simple select. I'm not precisely certain how it compares to the other two solutions above, but my intuition and experience (and I admit I might be wrong about it) is that it will be slower than a join, for example.

Comment: FWIW, my intuition tells me that your method is faster.

Comment: You're right, from a complexity standpoint it should be faster, being O(n+c) = O(n) compared to the O(n*(n+1)/2) = O(n^2) of a self join, it will "win" at some point, but I think that point is quite far, as i find the overhead (c) of having to read-compute-reassign the variables quite costly compared to the "regular" handling of a row (n), if that makes sense. I'm also don't exactly know the optimisation magic going on behind the scenes. Thank you for this discussion :)